# Error de conversión de un campo concatenado al ejecutar una vista en Oracle

Tags: html, oracle, xml, plsql

Tengo una vista (`DB_ADMIN.VW_DBA_MONITOR_CURRENTLYEXEC`) para poder visualizar las transacciones en Oracle. Dicha vista hace uso de las ya existentes en el sistema: `v$sql`, `V$SQLSTATS`, `v$sqlarea` y `gv$process`.

Y la estructura y tipo de columnas quedó de la siguiente manera:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Tengo un procedimiento que intenta usar dicha vista, formatear el resultado a una única cadena `HTML` bajo ciertas condiciones y enviarlo vía correo electrónico. A continuación, un resumen simple de dicho procedimiento:

```
DECLARE
    V_BODY_TEXT CLOB;
BEGIN
    select utl_i18n.unescape_reference(xmlagg(xmlelement(e,'
        <tr>
            <td>' || ltrim(rtrim(TO_CLOB(SID))) || '</th>  
            <td>' || ltrim(rtrim(TO_CLOB(SQL_ID))) || '</th>  
            <td>' || ltrim(rtrim(TO_CLOB(USERNAME))) || '</th>  
            <td>' || ltrim(rtrim(TO_CLOB(ONAME))) || '</th> 
            <td>' || ltrim(rtrim(TO_CLOB(MACHINE))) || '</th>  
            <td>' || ltrim(rtrim(TO_CLOB(WAIT_CLASS))) || '</th>  
            <td>' || ltrim(rtrim(TO_CLOB(EVENT))) || '</th>  
            <td>' || ltrim(rtrim(TO_CLOB(MODULE))) || '</th>  
            <td>' || ltrim(rtrim(TO_CLOB(LOGON_TIME))) || '</th>  
            <td>' || ltrim(rtrim(TO_CLOB(START_TIME))) || '</th>  
            <td>' || ltrim(rtrim(TO_CLOB(TIME))) || '</th>  
            <td>' || ltrim(rtrim(TO_CLOB(SQL_TEXT))) || '</th>
        </tr>
    ','').extract('//text()')).getclobval()) x
    INTO V_BODY_TEXT
    FROM DB_ADMIN.VW_DBA_MONITOR_CURRENTLYEXEC WHERE "TIME" > 300;
               
END;
```

El error que presenta la ejecución del código anterior es debido a que el resultado concatenado solo admite 4000 caractares y no importa si trato de hacer el cast (`TO_CLOB`) campo por campo o a toda la cadena concatenada, me sigue saliendo el mismo error cada vez que se supera el tamaño del resultado:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

A cerca del código anterior, el uso de la función `TO_CLOB`, es mi último intento por tratar de solucionar el problema.

Dicho error, tampoco permite aplicarle alguna acción tipo "substring" o un "len".

También intenté crear una tabla con todos los campos de tipo `CLOB`, luego insertar el resultado de la vista y usar el procedimiento anterior ahora con la tabla, pero sigo obteniendo el mismo error cada vez que el código html genearado supera los 4000 caracteres.

Por lo que, acudo a esta comunidad para ver qué otras opciones me dan para poder salir del problema.

Comment: El procedimiento que nos compartes no realiza el envió del correo. ¿Por otro lado porque estas haciendo un TO_CLOB a cada campo? cuando haces TO_CLOB(USERNAME) lo que estas haciendo es convertir a clob una variable que a lo más tiene 128 caracteres. ¿porque usas ltrim(rtrim(...))   en lugar de solo usar trim(...)?   ¿Porque no solo concatenas todo? por las longitudes de los tipos de dato que estas usando en la tabla no parece que vayas a superar los 4000 caracteres que soporta un varchar2. Es decir V_BODY_TEXT pudiera ser también de tipo VARCHAR2(4000)

Comment: Sería bueno que también indicaras porque usas xmlagg. No le veo sentido si tu mismo estas generando el html y si los datos ya estan en columnas separadas.

Comment: Por favor también aclara porque usas utl_i18n.unescape_reference para envolver a todo el concatenado.

Comment: @AlvaroC. Por eso puse que el procedimiento indicando en la consulta solo es un resumen, por eso no puse la parte del envío del correo. Ya que el problema no radica con el envío si no con el desbordamiento del tamaño. Por otro lado, no deberías suponer que no superará los 4000 caracteres, porque también puse el error que salió y claramente indica que sí se superó. Las razones de usar el `TO_CLOB`, nuevamente, fue un intento de solucionar el problema, por eso acudo a esta plataforma. En este caso uso xml porque la función `LISTAGG` también me arrojó el mismo error.

Comment: @AlvaroC. Sobre el uso de la función `utl_i18n.unescape_reference`, es para poder quitar los caracteres especiales que se generan al usar la función xml. ¿Con estas indicaciones ya podrías ayudarme?

Comment: Hola Fran.J. Una duda más. ¿Puedes indicarnos que versión de Oracle utilizas?

Comment: @AlvaroC. La versión del Oracle que estoy usando es el 19c.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Al final, la solución que encontré para evitar las distintas restricciones de las funciones usadas para generar código `xml` o conversores como la función `utl_i18n.unescape_reference`, fue usar un `loop` con `FOR`:

```
DECLARE
    V_BODY CLOB;
    V_TABLE_BODY CLOB := NULL;

BEGIN

    --> DataSource:
    FOR r IN (
        SELECT  SID,  
                SQL_ID,
                USERNAME,
                ONAME,
                MACHINE,
                WAIT_CLASS,
                EVENT,
                MODULE,
                LOGON_TIME,
                START_TIME,
                TIME,
                SQL_TEXT
        FROM    DB_ADMIN.VW_DBA_MONITOR_CURRENTLYEXEC
        WHERE   "TIME" > 300
    )
    LOOP
        --> Table Body:
        V_TABLE_BODY := V_TABLE_BODY ||
            '<tr>'||
                '<td>'||trim(r.SID)||'</td>' ||
                '<td>'||trim(r.SQL_ID)||'</td>' ||
                '<td>'||trim(r.USERNAME)||'</td>' ||
                '<td>'||trim(r.ONAME)||'</td>' ||
                '<td>'||trim(r.MACHINE)||'</td>' ||
                '<td>'||trim(r.WAIT_CLASS)||'</td>' ||
                '<td>'||trim(r.EVENT)||'</td>' ||
                '<td>'||trim(r.MODULE)||'</td>' ||
                '<td>'||trim(r.LOGON_TIME)||'</td>' ||
                '<td>'||trim(r.START_TIME)||'</td>' ||
                '<td>'||trim(r.TIME)||'</td>' ||
                '<td>'||trim(r.SQL_TEXT)||'</td>' ||
            '</tr>';

    END LOOP;
    ----

    IF V_TABLE_BODY IS NOT NULL THEN
        --> HTML Body:
        V_BODY :=
        '
            <body>
                <table border="1">
                    <tr>
                        <th>SID</th>  
                        <th>SQL_ID</th>  
                        <th>USERNAME</th>  
                        <th>ONAME</th> 
                        <th>MACHINE</th>  
                        <th>WAIT_CLASS</th>  
                        <th>EVENT</th>  
                        <th>MODULE</th>  
                        <th>LOGON_TIME</th>  
                        <th>START_TIME</th>  
                        <th>TIME</th>  
                        <th>SQL_TEXT</th>
                    </tr>' ||
                    V_TABLE_BODY || --> Table Body
                '</table>
            </body>
        ';
                    
    -- Send Mail:
    DB_ADMIN.USP_SEND_MAIL(V_BODY); --> Referential
        
END IF;
```